# Ruby on Rails - AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails app and I am currently getting this message.  What's the best way to go about resolving this issue?

Ruby 2.5.8
Rails 5.2

Following AWS Gems are available:

```
  * aws-eventstream (1.1.0)
  * aws-partitions (1.417.0)
  * aws-sdk-core (3.111.2)
  * aws-sdk-kms (1.41.0)
  * aws-sdk-s3 (1.87.0)
  * aws-sdk-v1 (1.67.0)
  * aws-ses (0.7.1)
  * aws-sigv4 (1.2.2)
```

> AWS::SES::ResponseError: InvalidClientTokenId - Signature Version
> 3 requests are deprecated from March 1, 2021.
> From that date on, we are progressively rejecting
> such requests. To resolve the issue you must migrate to
> Signature Version 4. If you are self-

Thank you!

Comment: I  don't think you have any other options here as in the error message says `March 1, 2021. From that date on, we are progressively rejecting such requests. ` You have to consider upgrading the gems

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution to this? I am having the same issue with signature 4

Comment: @chirag.sweng I did! see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430073/