# AWS::SES Response Error: InvalidClientTokenId - Signature Version 3 requests are deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am using aws-sdk in my rails project to send emails.
currently I am getting an error as follows

"AWS::SES Response Error: InvalidClientTokenId - Signature Version 3 requests are deprecated from March 1, 2021. From that date on, we are progressively rejecting such requests. To resolve the issue you must migrate to Signature Version 4. If you are self-signing your requests, refer to the documentation for Authenticating requests to the Amazon SES API [1] with Signature Version 4 [2]. If you are not self-signing your requests, simply update your SDK/CLI to the latest version.

As per documentation,I have updated the gems in my project
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'
gem 'aws-ses', '~> 0.7.1'

Still ended up with same error. Please help on this

Comment: Can you share your SES configuration? I suppose you're somewhere calling `add_action_mailer_delivery_method` isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Changed my gem,
Gemfile

```
gem "aws-ses", git: "https://github.com/zebitex/aws-ses.git", ref: "78-sigv4-problem"
```

config/initializers/amazon_ses.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
access_key_id: "abc",
secret_access_key: "pqr",
signature_version: 4
```

Please refer https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses/issues/83

Comment: This solved my issue as well - thank you for posting!